# Condition for Input field to enter less amount compared to other Input field in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 2 input values named Budget and Earning, so I want Budget to be entered only if it is less than Earning, otherwise no.

How should I condition them: can we use a ternary operator here?

```
<BudgetInput value={BudgetInputValue}>
<EarningInput value={EarningInputValue}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the disabled prop in the input element...and add the condition like:

```
disabled={BudgetInput >= EarningInput}
```

Comment: you can directly use `disabled={BudgetInput >= EarningInput}`

Comment: @saksh73 It disables the textbox permanently , whereas I want to allow the user to edit the value and adjust it properly

Comment: @ZamirManihar it disables the textbox

Comment: @Rupam I am assuming you are using hooks, and `BudgetInput` `EarningInput` are states, so use `onChange` on fields to change the state variable `BudgetInput` `EarningInput` values

Comment: @Rupam you want the user to enter the Budget Input in the range of EarningInput...right?